# Trying to create a Big Endian environment using solaris 10 SPARC VM in Windows8 Host

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, virtual-machine, solaris

I need a Big Endian system for testing.

I am planning to create a Solaris Virtual Machine by installing 
Oracle Solaris 10 SPARC(http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris10/downloads/index.html) inside a virtual machine.

I am using Oracle Virtualbox software in my Windows 8.1 machine.
Its processor hardware is Intel core i-5.

Will it work ? because somebody told me Big Endianness is a CPU property rather than OS. Or is there any download link to get a Solaris 10 Big Endian VM template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run Sparc software on x86 processor (w/o special emulator).

And as endianness is processor related you can try to rent virtual machine (Sparc, Power)

About renting: there are several [companies](http://www.alpha-digital.co.uk/Pages/Rental.html), which offer renting server.

You can also find some offers for virtual machines, like [this](http://www.polarhome.com) or [this](http://lparbox.com/aix-cloud).

Comment: could you please elaborate what is this special emulator approach ? Also what is the source for getting rent for virtual machine ( Sparc, Power )

Comment: You can try qemu to run solaris sparc on x86. But do not expect miracles in sense of speed :) About renting: there are several companies, which offer renting server, this for example: http://www.alpha-digital.co.uk/Pages/Rental.html You can also find some offers for virtual machines, like this: http://www.polarhome.com/ or this: http://lparbox.com/aix-cloud. Will add the links to the answer for completeness